# npm package not installing as expected

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, npm-install

I am new to NPM and angular2, i am trying to create my own NPM package and install it locally. I manage to create the package alright (test-package-0.0.1.tgz) which contains:

```
├── .npmignore
├── README.md
├── LICENSE               
├── index.html             
├── package.json           
├── main.js 
├── styles.css
├── tsconfig.json
├── typings.json        
├── app                       
│   └── app.component.ts
│   └── app.module.ts
│   └── main.js
│   └── main.ts
```

However when i try and install it in a different directory i only get a `node_modules` folder.

I am using `npm pack` to create `test-package-0.0.1.tgz`

and `npm install C:\otherfolder\platform-core-webui-0.0.1.tgz` to install the package.

Here is the contents of my `package.json` file and im running in a Windows environment.

```
{
  "name": "test-package",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Test package",
  "author": "me",
  "publishConfig": {
    "registry": "http://localnpmrepository/npm"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings"
  },
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.0.2",
    "@angular/core": "~2.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.0.2",
    "@angular/http": "~2.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.0.2",
    "@angular/router": "~3.0.2",
    "@angular/upgrade": "~2.0.2",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.1.5",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "systemjs": "0.19.39",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.25"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^3.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "typescript": "^2.0.3",
    "typings": "^1.4.0"
  },
  "main": "main.js"
}
```

I was hoping to see the exact same folder structure after my install not just a `node_modules` folder. Where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I believe i might have misunderstood the mechanics of creating your own package/module! Module being the key word, of course when i installed my platform-core-webui-0.0.1.tgz it installed itself inside the `node_modules` folder where i now need to `import` it into a component to use. So that answers my question :)